# Missing hadoop package in Bigtop (centos) - installation issue

Tags: linux, hadoop, centos, yum, bigtop

I am trying to install bigtop on centos6 (VM using virtualbox).
I am following links given below with little modifications to get latest versions (bigtop 1.1.0) -

http://www.dummies.com/how-to/content/set-up-the-hadoop-environment-with-apache-bigtop.html
https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/BIGTOP/How+to+install+Hadoop+distribution+from+Bigtop+0.5.0

To be precise, I have run following commands till now -

```
wget -O /etc/yum.repos.d/bigtop.repo http://www.apache.org/dist/bigtop/bigtop-1.1.0/repos/centos6/bigtop.repo
yum install hadoop\* mahout\* oozie\* hbase\* hive\* hue\* pig\* zookeeper\*
```

Now the problem is, it says -

```
No package hadoop* available. 
No package hue* available.
No package zookeeper* available.
```

I am new to linux and don't completely understand what exactly these commands are doing. I have wasted an entire day on this. As I am just trying to explore hadoop on my VM, I am fine if I can get some older version of bigtop too  but I would prefer that I can get atleast hadoop 2.0 or above.

Can someone help on this?

Thanks.

Comment: Did you manage to figure this out?

Comment: Nope.. but then I moved to Hortonworks package pre-installed free VM on Microsoft Azure (1 month free trial)..

Answer (score 0):

You have to run `sudo apt-get update` between adding new repository and installing packages from it.